# Setting a bit of bytea column using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which has a column of type bytea. I want to update it and set 76th bit as 1. What query should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the 42nd bit to 1, you could use

```
UPDATE tab
SET binval = set_bit(binval, 41, 1)
WHERE ...
```

Note that you may be faster with such operations (but waste space) if you change the column to `EXTERNAL` instead of `EXTENDED` storage (see the [TOAST documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html)).

Comment: Thanks a lot Laurenz